# How to write min max objective function in CPLEX using OPL?

Tags: cplex, opl

I am new to CPLEX and I am struggling to write the following min max objective function. This is my first question on Stack Overflow so I cannot post an image, but this is the equation written in latex:

```
$$\sum_{a=1}^A min ( max \sum_{b=1}^B \sum_{c=1}^C \sum_{d=1}^D t_{d_a}*x_{adbc})$$
```

Comment: What have you tried in OPL, and what error messages did you get. Or did the syntax work but give the wrong answer?

Comment: @TimChippingtonDerrick My syntax was correct with no error messages. I cannot get around the logic of OPL and how to write such objective there. I am confused

Comment: Again - what did you actually write in OPL? Even if what you wrote is incomplete, it is often easier to comment if we have something specific to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example in [Model Building](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/model-building-oplcplex-alex-fleischer/) Problem 13 [Market Sharing](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/modelbuilding/blob/master/marketsharing.mod)

```
dvar float obj1;
dvar float obj2;

//minimize obj1*1000+obj2; // without staticLex
minimize staticLex(obj1,obj2);  // with staticLex

subject to
{
obj1==sum(i in 1..nbConstraints) abs(tolerance[i]); // First objective
obj2==max(i in 1..nbConstraints) abs(tolerance[i]); // Second objective
```

obj2 is a minimax

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply (internet connectivity issues). I want to make sure that I understand. So you put the objective as constraints. Then, you minimize obj2 which is a max making it minmax. Am I correct? If yes, then I am still confused on where I should put the summation before the minmax. I know programming but I am confused with OPL.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the OPL syntax can itself be an big issue. I definitely find it simpler if I don't try to squeeze complex expressions into one line, and break these expressions into smaller parts and build them up incrementally. Once you get something like what you want working in smaller pieces, it is often easy to then build up from that into a smaller or neater format if you want that.

If it is the logic of how to model or create a 'minimax' objective, I can try to explain how I think about it.

Assume we have a set of variables or expressions V, then we can create a new variable (lets call it maxV) and add constraints so that maxV is greater or equal to every variable in V. Then to get our minimax objective we need to minimise that new variable maxV.

I am not sure that I understand your LaTeX equation: it comes out like this:

[image]

It looks from this equation that you have a sum over a set of these minimax-type expressions. If that is true, then we can just repeat the above pattern and minimise the sum of a set of minimax expressions. So we have multiple sets V_i, and for each set V_i we can create our extra variable maxV_i which is constrained to be greater or equal to all the variables in the corresponding set V_i. Finally we can then sum our set of maxV_i variables and use that as our objective.